# Why aren't constructor and static function tear-offs, with extending type parameters, identical when the base type is omitted or included?

Tags: dart

Consider the following class:

```dart
class MyClass<T extends num> {
  const MyClass();

  void instanceFunction() {}

  static void staticFunction<T extends num>() {}
}
```

The following expressions are all `true`:

```dart
identical(const MyClass(), const MyClass<num>());
identical(const MyClass.new(), const MyClass<num>.new());
identical(const MyClass().instanceFunction, const MyClass<num>().instanceFunction);

identical(MyClass.new, MyClass.new);
identical(MyClass<num>.new, MyClass<num>.new);
identical(MyClass.staticFunction, MyClass.staticFunction);
identical(MyClass.staticFunction<num>, MyClass.staticFunction<num>);
```

But when the base type, `num`, is included in one tear-off, such as in the expressions below, they are `false`:

```dart
identical(MyClass.new, MyClass<num>.new);
identical(MyClass.staticFunction, MyClass.staticFunction<num>);
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: When the generic type parameter uses `extends`, leaving it out will default to the base class. This can be see in the first `true` expression I list. Why do the `const` constructions result in the same object, but have different tear-offs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The `true` cases:

> ```dart
> identical(const MyClass(), const MyClass<num>());
> ```

You *instantiate* an `MyClass` object.  Since `MyClass` is declared with `MyClass<T extends num>`, `MyClass()` with no explicit type specified is shorthand for `MyClass<num>()`.  This expression therefore is the same as `identical(const MyClass<num>, const MyClass<num>)`, which should obviously be true.

> ```dart
> identical(const MyClass.new(), const MyClass<num>.new());
> ```

This is just a more roundabout version of the previous case.

> ```dart
> identical(const MyClass().instanceFunction, const MyClass<num>().instanceFunction);
> ```

This is true for the same reason as the first case. `const MyClass()` is shorthand for `const MyClass<num>()`, `const` instances are canonicalized, so you're comparing `.instanceFunction` members of the exact same object.

> ```dart
> identical(MyClass.new, MyClass.new);
> ```

Both arguments are the same and both are statically-known at compile-time, so there's no reason for this to be false.

> ```dart
> identical(MyClass<num>.new, MyClass<num>.new);
> ```

This would be true for the same reason as the previous case.

> ```dart
> identical(MyClass.staticFunction, MyClass.staticFunction);`
> identical(MyClass.staticFunction<num>, MyClass.staticFunction<num>);
> ```

Both arguments to `identical` are the same, so that these evaluate to `true` shouldn't be surprising.

### The `false` cases:

> ```dart
> identical(MyClass.new, MyClass<num>.new);
> identical(MyClass.staticFunction, MyClass.staticFunction<num>);
> ```

`MyClass.new` and `MyClass.staticFunction` are *not* shorthand for `MyClass<num>.new` and `MyClass.staticFunction<num>` respectively; they evaluate to generic functions:

```dart
var c1 = MyClass.new;
var c2 = MyClass<num>.new;

var f1 = MyClass.staticFunction;
var f2 = MyClass.staticFunction<num>;
```

then the type of `c1` is `MyClass<T> Function<T extends num>()` and the type of `c2` is `MyClass<num> Function()`.  Similarly, the type of `f1` is `void Function<T extends num>()` but the type of `f2` is `void Function()`. `c1` and `f1` are still generic; you can do `c1<num>()` or `f2<double>()` later.

`c2` and `f2` have the type parameter statically bound already, so they have a different type and clearly should not be the same as `c1` and `f1` respectively.

A more interesting case is:

```dart
identical(f1<num>, MyClass.staticFunction<num>))
```

which evaluates to `false`.  Why isn't this the same as the `identical(MyClass.staticFunction<num>, MyClass.staticFunction<num>)` case?  I'm not sure exactly why, but I would presume that it's an implementation detail from the Dart compiler being able to trivially canonicalize `MyClass.staticFunction<num>` at compilation-time but not `f1<num>` due to `f1` being potentially variable.

Comment: Sorry about the problematic generic constructor tear-off syntax; I've fixed it.

Comment: I understand why the true cases are true - but you are wrong about your explanations for the false cases. `identical(MyClass.new, MyClass<num>.new)` does not evaluate to `true` on any platform that I've tested on. I also thought it should - hence my question!

Comment: Your static function syntax is also wrong. `MyClass<num>.staticFunction` makes no sense - static functions do not have access to class generic types, and this does not compile. And are you sure that "`MyClass.staticFunction` is not shorthand for `MyClass.staticFunction<num>`"? It seems to be, experimentally.

Comment: @hacker1024 Oops, you're right.  I'm not sure why I seemed to observe `identical(MyClass.new, MyClass<num>.new)` being `true`; I might have mixed up the result with a different case or made a typo.  The `MyClass<num>.staticFunction` thing was a mistake; corrected.

Comment: @hacker1024 You can clearly observe that the types of `MyClass.staticFunction` and `MyClass.staticFunction<num>` are different, so the former is not shorthand for the latter.  If, however, you *invoke* the functions, then `MyClass.staticFunction()` *is* shorthand for `MyClass.staticFunction<num>()`.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know that constructor tear-offs can be generic functions. This clears it up!